# How to build a vector via a call to reduce

Tags: exception, vector, clojure, arity

I'm trying to figure why this particular function isn't working as expected. I suspect from the error message that it has something to do with the way I'm creating the empty vector for the accumulator.

I have a simple function that returns a sequence of 2-element vectors:

```
(defn zip-with-index
  "Returns a sequence in which each element is of the
   form [i c] where i is the index of the element and c
   is the element at that index."
   [coll]
   (map-indexed (fn [i c] [i c]) coll))
```

That works fine. The problem comes when I try to use it in another function

```
(defn indexes-satisfying
  "Returns a vector containing all indexes of coll that satisfy
   the predicate p."
  [p coll]
  (defn accum-if-satisfies [acc zipped]
    (let [idx (first zipped)
          elem (second zipped)]
      (if (p elem) 
        (conj acc idx)
        (acc))))
  (reduce accum-if-satisfies (vector) (zip-with-index coll)))
```

It compiles, but when I attempt to use it I get an error:

```
user=> (indexes-satisfying (partial > 3) [1 3 5 7])
ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentVector
clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:437)
```

I can't figure out what's going wrong here. Also if there is a more 'Clojure-like' way of doing what I'm trying to do, I'm interested in hearing about that also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably on the else clause of `accum-if-satisfies`, should be just `acc` not `(acc)`.

You could use `filter` and then `map` instead of `reduce`. Like that:

```
(map #(first %) 
     (filter #(p (second %))
             (zip-with-index coll)))
```

You could also call `map-indexed` with `vector` instead of `(fn [i c] [i c])`. 
The whole code would look like that:

```
(defn indexes-satisfying
  [p coll]
  (map #(first %)
       (filter #(p (second %))
               (map-indexed vector coll))))
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Such a small thing. I like your version a lot better also.

Answer (score 2):

As for a more Clojure-like way, you could use

```
(defn indexes-satisfying [pred coll]
  (filterv #(pred (nth coll %))
           (range (count coll))))
```

Use `filter` instead of `filterv` to return a lazy seq rather than a vector.

Also, you should not use `defn` to define inner functions; it will instead define a global function in the namespace where the inner function is defined and have subtle side effects besides that. Use `letfn` instead:

```
(defn outer [& args]
  (letfn [(inner [& inner-args] ...)]
    (inner ...)))
```

Comment: That implementation is much cleaner than what I was going for. I didn't know nested defn's leaked into the global namespace. That's good information. I was assuming scoping rules similar to Scala.

Comment: `def*` forms are simply not meant for introducing local bindings; `let` and `letfn` are available for that. The sole purpose of `def` is to create global Vars in the current namespace (where "current namespace" is determined at compile time). `defn`, `defmacro` and such expand to `def`. Also, those `def`-introduced global Vars are created right away, even if the `def` form is buried inside a function body, say, though they receive no binding until that piece code is "executed". (Of course somebody could come along between the two points in time and give the Var a root binding.)

Answer (score 1):

One more way to do it would be:

```
(defn indexes-satisfying [p coll]
  (keep-indexed #(if (p %2) % nil) coll))
```